# How to stop Browsers from caching JSON files?

Tags: json, caching, browser, browser-cache

I made a little website that simply shows a table with content fetched from a json file.
Everything works fine, but for whatever reasons Chrome keeps caching the JSON file. I need to hit Shift+F5 all the time to update the page content. I could of course disable this in Chrome but I also want some friends to use this site so it would be nice, if there was a workaround I could put into my scripts to stop the browser from caching. I have a webserver, but I don't have root access so I can't modify much on the server itself. Is there some code I could put into my php site to get it done?

I searched for some solutions on Google, but most solutions assume, you have a root server, but I don't have one.

Here's my code:

The updater:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Test-Updater</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="">Append Data to JSON File</h3><br/>                 
                <form method="post" action="jsonproc.php">
                     <br />  
                     <label>Titel</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"/><br/>  
                     <label>Genre</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="genre" class="form-control"/><br/>  
                     <label>Bewertung</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="rating" class="form-control"/><br/>
                     
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Append" class="btn btn-info"/><br/>
                </form>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

The Viewer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Movie List</h2>
        <table id = "tb1" border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>Titel</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Bewertung</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            fetch("boli.db")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    for (var i = 0; i<data.movies.length; i++){
                        let vtitle = data.movies[i].title;
                        let vgenre = data.movies[i].genre;
                        let vrating = data.movies[i].rating;
                            document.querySelector("#tb1").innerHTML += `
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${vtitle}</td>
                                    <td>${vgenre}</td>
                                    <td>${vrating}</td>
                                </tr>`;
                    }
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the JSON php:

```
<?php 
       
        $title = $_POST['title']; 
        $genre = $_POST['genre'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $file_name='boli.db';
   
        if(file_exists("$file_name")) {
            
            $db_data= file_get_contents($file_name);
            $decoded_data = json_decode($db_data, true);
            
            $new_data['title'] = $title;
            $new_data['genre'] = $genre;
            $new_data['rating'] = $rating;
            
            array_push($decoded_data['movies'], array('title' => $new_data['title'], 'genre' => $new_data['genre'], 'rating' => $new_data['rating']));
            
            $jsonData = json_encode($decoded_data);
            file_put_contents($file_name, $jsonData);
            unset($decoded_data);
        }
        
        else { 
            echo "file not exist<br/>";   
        } 
?>
```